# QNX ELF File Format

Tags: linker, elf, qnx

I am trying to figure out the differences between ELF executables linked for QNX and Linux, respectively.

Is the exact ELF executable format needed by QNX documented somewhere? Minimally, what sections, segments, entries, etc. do I need in an ELF file to get the QNX loader to execute the instruction at the specified entry point?

Comment: I have no any experience with QNX system. More close I get was this link(http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/sys_arch/dll.html) by googling. Grab all the documentation and if you still didn't find what you're looking for ask in the QNX community/forum (I've see one there) someone in there should knows. EDIT: Is this ELF file generated by your own tool? if so, you still have the option to read the source code of tools like ld/gcc and try figure out how it works.

Comment: I have also found that link. I still do not know if there are differences between, say, a Linux ELF file and a QNX ELF file. I do know, however, that programs compiled with Go's 8g compiler for linux/386 do run on QNX. By run I don't mean "the program works", but "the QNX loader loads the linux binary and starts execution at the entry point". These binaries fail upon the first linux style syscall INT 0x80, generating a segfault, which is only to be expected.

Comment: They certainly does differ, like (almost, if not all) every platform which does use ELF. Which basically differ is also syscalls(you already mentioned) and things like calling conventions. They may be similar but isn't guaranteed to be the same unless documentation says unlike. In your case it seem you're trying to distribute for compiled linux compiled program to run fine in another platform? for the previously reasons I've mentioned don't do that. Get a compiler for QNX and re-compile your program to this platform. They have a very nice SDK as I seen on its web site.

Comment: I completely understand that a program compiled for Linux will not run on QNX. I was looking into porting the Go toolchain from [golang.org](http://golang.org) to QNX. On one of the most basic levels, this means that I might need to alter the Go linker to produce binaries for QNX. In my case it turned out that the ELF files produced by the Go linker would run (as in "executing instruction") on QNX just fine. Of course the whole runtime and platform support code will need to be ported to QNX - but the Go linker does not seem to need changes for this application.